# How to copy one node and change another

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

now i'm stuck with simple task.
I have
Code:

```
<m:node1>
...
</m:node1>
<namespace:something attribute1='1'/>
<namespaceOther:other attribute1='2'/>
<namespaceOther:some attribute1='1'/>
```

So if attribute1=1 i need this:

```
<m:node1>
...
</m:node1>
<namespace:something attribute1='1'/>
<namespaceOther:some attribute1='1'/>
```

What I need to do is copy `<m:node1>` with all its children and check if `<namespace:* attribute1` is equal something then copy it, else not.

I would like something like `<template match="*:*">` but that's not possible.
Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="m:node1" />
<xsl:copy-of select="*[@attribute1='1']" />
```